# Take user input and search Static directory

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7

My task is to create an app that lets users search for a file in a static directory (shared drive).  I have a textbox for users to input a full file name or partial file name (as determined by the user).  What I would like is for it to take the user input and query the directory and return all matching values to a listbox.

For the purposes of this question...the directory is:

```
 @("\\server\directory\folder\subfolder\")
```

and the input from the user is stored as:

```
string search;
```

**Edit**

Here is the code that I have so far.

```
string search;
search = searchTB.ToString();
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@("\\server\directory\folder\subfolder\");

// For a partial match
foreach (var fi in di.GetFiles("*" + search + "*"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
    statusCodeLB.Items.Add(fi.Name);
}

// For an exact match
foreach (var fi in di.GetFiles(search))
{
     Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
     statusCodeLB.Items.Add(fi.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
string directory = @"\\server\directory\folder\subfolder\";
string search = "userInput";
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(directory).Where(file => file.Contains(search));
```

After this you only have to bind the data to your listbox and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DirectoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class, in particular [`GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\directory\folder\subfolder\");

// For a partial match
foreach (var fi in di.GetFiles("*" + search + "*"))
{
  Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
}

// For an exact match
foreach (var fi in di.GetFiles(search))
{
  Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
}
```

The MSDN pages linked above have full details of the options you can use.

Comment: I tried your code, but it did not produce any results.  I tried changing Console.WriteLine to ListBox.Items.Add, but it did not make a difference.

Comment: I also tried adding ListBox.Items.Add(fi.Name) to each of the foreach loops...but that did not make a difference either.

Comment: Do you mean by stepping in or adding a MessageBox.show "some text" or ("var".ToString()) inside of the loop and see if the message box displays?

Comment: Stepping through... drop a break point inside the foreach and see if you get there.

Comment: When I start debugging with a breakpoint inside the first loop, nothing unusual happens (no errors).  If I press the "search button", it displays the code and highlights the line with the breakpoint.  But it does not let me step in/through until I initiate the search.  The events window shows that the breakpoint was hit.

Comment: if you hit the breakpoint, then something somewhere else is clearing your listbox.

Comment: I added a message box at the end of one of the loops and pressing the button does not initiate the messagebox to display.